# Loading big data to elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Firstly i do not like asking questions without code but I could not find any solution and need help about requesting big log datas from kibana and elasticsearch too.

I am trying to get 10000 documents from kibana on discover panel but it get me error. Error is : my 10000 documents are 5gb size and it just allows 2gb , I searched about spliting data but i could not do that on kibana.

i also tried
    `_msearch`
it is not what i look for.

1- Do you guyz can tell me how can i do (if its possible) scroll on kibana - discover.

2- How can i get bigger datas from 2gb ?

if you can give me examples or link resources i will be so pleased.

Comment: Must you use kibana to browse through 10k documents? Most UIs are not designed to scroll through that many individual rows. Elasticsearch itself can easily dump out as much data as you want, and you can just as easily browse relevant subsets of data in Kibana.

Comment: Actually i do not know if i will use 10000 documents but i do not know how to search documents bigger from 2gb. I wonder what should i do if i need bigger than 2gb.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to search above 10k docs on the discover module?

If im undestanding well you want to download more than 2gb of data from Kibana, right? Put this on the Kibana.yml: xpack.reporting.csv.maxSizeBytes: 50971520